# Using BeginCollectionItem in ASP.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, begincollectionitem

I cannot use BeginCollectionItem by Steve Anderson in asp.net core. I got an error in my partial view when I use

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Entries")) 
{

}
```

The type 'HtmlHelper' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

is there an alternative way to achieve the functionality of BeginCollectionItem in ASP.net core?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ported the original BeginCollectionItem to work with ASP.Net Core on .Net Core and .Net Framework 4.6+.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItemCore

Comment: Thank you. I've added the package to my project but I'm still not able to use BeginItemCollection. Still says I'm missing a reference in my view. Not sure how I'm supposed to get this working :/

Comment: DanielJackson Add this line in _ViewImports.cshtml :  
    @using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItemCore;